# How many chamomile seeds should I plant?

Tags: seedlings

I sprinkled chamomile seeds in a small pot about 20cm. Almost a hundered seedlings have sprouted and I've read that you should thin to one per pot. Clearly I've gone wrong with my sowing and planted at too many.

Should I drastically thin out my chamomile or are you supposed to have many growing together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sowed straight into a small pot, then you need to remove all but one to allow it to grow to maturity. If you sow into a seed tray, spreading a pinch or two of seeds evenly, when they germinate and get two sets of leaves, you prick those out into individual pots to grow on. You can try pricking out some of the others in your pot if they have 2 sets of leaves, but one seedling to a pot is necessary.

Next time you sow seeds, bear in mind that each seed represents one plant - depending which chamomile you're growing, each seed means a plant that grows to 4 inches or 20 inches high, by 18 to 24 inches - in order to do that, each one needs to develop its own extensive root system. Sowing into a pot, you only needed to plant four to six seeds maximum, removing all but the strongest one as they grew.

Comment: thank you! I think it was because there were thousands of seeds in the packet and they were so tiny I stupidly assumed I would need to sprinkle lots of them. Much appreciated advice.